# Javascript Breakout game. Changing ball speed at score interval

Tags: javascript, if-statement, intervals, breakout

I am looking for a little help on adding on to some code for a Breakout game using Javascript within Tumult Hype. I am looking to make it so that once you hit a certain score the ball speed will increase.

Here is the code so far without the speed booster.

```
var input1 = event.which || event.keyCode;

if ((input1 == "37") && (window.setLoopLeft == false)) { // LEFT ARROW PRESSED
    window.setLoopLeft = true;
    window.intervalLeft = setInterval(moveLeft, 5);
} else if ((input1 == "39") && (window.setLoopRight == false)) { // RIGHT ARROW PRESSED
    window.setLoopRight = true;
    window.intervalRight = setInterval(moveRight, 5);
} else if ((input1 == "32") && (window.ballLaunched == false)) { // SPACE BAR PRESSED
    window.ballLaunched = true;
    // RUN THE MOVEBALL FUNCTION EVERY 10 MILLISECONDS
    window.intervalMoveBall = setInterval(moveBall, window.ballSpeed);
}

function moveBall() {
    var ballLeft = parseInt(hypeDocument.getElementById("ball").style.left);
    var ballTop = parseInt(hypeDocument.getElementById("ball").style.top);
```

This is the code I am adding onto. Now what I was planning was to do what create a global variable to apply to the window.intervalMoveBall. I would then write a new function that would detect the score value at 1000 points and double the balls speed making it move every 5 miliseconds instead of 10.

Now what I am not sure how to do is actually write the if statement so that it detects the score value.  I was wondering if anybody might be able to show me how to right that or even be able to tell me if using a global and a new function with an if statement will even work for this or not.

Comment: How are you moving the ball currently, and how are you keeping score?

Comment: There are separate function that occurs when the page initializes for the score. That code is

hypeDocument.getElementById("scoreValue2").innerHTML = window.score;

The ball moves on a set angle based on where it hits each block or the paddle bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using setInterval, so to change the time interval you would have to clear the original interval, and start a new one with the new time interval.  A simpler approach is to make the moveBall function responsible for calling itself with a setTimeout (and the same for the moveLeft and moveRight), like this...

```
var input1 = event.which || event.keyCode;

if ((input1 == "37") && (window.setLoopLeft == false)) { // LEFT ARROW PRESSED
    window.setLoopLeft = true;
    window.intervalLeft = setInterval(moveLeft, 5);
} else if ((input1 == "39") && (window.setLoopRight == false)) { // RIGHT ARROW PRESSED
    window.setLoopRight = true;
    window.intervalRight = setInterval(moveRight, 5);
} else if ((input1 == "32") && (window.ballLaunched == false)) { // SPACE BAR PRESSED
    window.ballLaunched = true;
    moveBall();
}

function moveBall() {
    setTimeout(moveBall, window.ballSpeed);
    // the rest of your moveBall function
}
```

This means that we can set a different timespan every time moveBall runs, with some conditional logic, for example,

```
function moveBall() {
    setTimeout(moveBall, window.score > 1000 : 5 ? 10);
    // the rest of your moveBall function
}
```

Obviously this is an infinite loop, so you would also want to add some way of stopping this, such as a check that the game hasn't finished, for example,

```
function moveBall() {
    if (window.gameFinished) {
        return;
    }

    setTimeout(moveBall, window.score > 1000 : 5 ? 10);
    // the rest of your moveBall function
}
```

Just as an aside, it can get quite unmaintainable to use lots of global variables stored on the window object, so it might be worth looking into JavaScript namespacing.